# convert to Date format in MM/YY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am converting date into `MM/YY`, but it is converted to varchar. How to change that back to datetime datatype?

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), e.[Start_Date], 3), 5) AS 'Month/Year'
from table1
```

Comment: Dates have year and month and day components in T-SQL.  Which day of the month do you want to use?

Comment: `SELECT DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, e.start_date), 0) FROM table1 As e` This will give you the first of the month as a `datetime` value. Is that what you're aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

```
I am converting date into MM/YY, but it is converted to varchar. How to change that back to datetime datatype?
```

does this mean you are updating back same field with varchar value.How this is possible ?
where is date field lost ?

```
Declare @i datetime =getdate()
select stuff(convert(varchar(10),@i,103),1,3,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a value like "01/13" (Jan 2013) and you want to produce a `DATETIME` from it.

```
DECLARE @mmyy VARCHAR(5) = '01/13';
SELECT CAST('20'+RIGHT(@mmyy, 2)+'-'+LEFT(@mmyy, 2)+'-01' AS DATETIME)
-- returns 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Of course since your year is 2 digit I have to make the assumption that it's in the 21st century.